# Can I use Windows to Go as it were a Linux live distro?

Tags: windows, boot, multi-boot, liveusb, ramdisk

I hold a tablet with Windows 8 installed and I want to be able to boot a totally empty operative system from there when I cope with financial activities.

My primary option would be run a Linux live distro from a usb stick obviously, but since I tried that method and Linux doesn't recognize the network adapter yet, I would opte for one of the following solutions: installing a second Windows on a second partition of the internal ssd and use it for home banking only, or run Windows-to-go.

So my question is:

*- does **Windows-to-Go** boot from a usb stick and run **from RAM**, without persistence, as it were a **live distro**?*

Comment: Windows To Go requires Windows Enterprise.

Comment: http://lifehacker.com/how-to-run-a-portable-version-of-windows-from-a-usb-dri-1565509124  This may help you out with what you are looking for.

Comment: Without persistence? I don't believe so, no. I'd also predict Linux would generally have *better* driver support, although I have no data to back that up.

Comment: @DavidPostill I read that there are some tools which allows to create a Windows To Go stick from the 8.1 version as well...

Comment: [How to Create a Windows To Go USB Drive Without the Enterprise Edition](http://www.howtogeek.com/196817/how-to-create-a-windows-to-go-usb-drive-without-the-enterprise-edition/)

Comment: @Jonno unfortunately the network adapter of my Dell Venue pro 11 is not listed among the supported deviced which Linux already provided the drivers for..:/

Comment: @NetworkKingPin thank you for the link, I'll take a look

Comment: A Windows To Go system boots with internal disks offline by default. This is designed to prevent sensitive data from accidentally being saved onto an internal disk when using Windows To Go.

Comment: No; Windows To Go is not a live environment.  Any changes to the installation will persist through a reboot

Comment: Before you give up on Linux, can you identify the network adapter, which distros you've checked, and where have you looked for a Linux driver?

Comment: Nope, it acts like a normal Windows with persistent settings/applications . The advantage is that you can use it on different PCs/Hardware